# Error in this simple GUI program

Tags: java, swing

This simple program should be able to get the Markup percentage and the wholesale Cost and calculate the retail price i put an action listener to the *CALCULATE* button but when i press the calculate button this error appears:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
For input string: "Enter the markup precentage" 
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source) 
at mm$CalcListerner.actionPerformed(mm.java:58) 
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source) 
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone help me with this issue?

Can someone please explain these error messages because I don't really get any of that?

My code is:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class mm extends JFrame {

    private JTextField WholesaleCost;
    private JTextField markupPresentage;
    private JLabel WCost;
    private JLabel MPrecentage;
    private JButton button;
    private JPanel pannel;
    private final int Width = 250;
    private final int height = 320;

    public mm() {
        setTitle("Retail Price Calculator");
        setSize(Width, height);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        buildPanel();
        add(pannel);
    }

    private void buildPanel() {
        WholesaleCost = new JTextField(10);
        markupPresentage = new JTextField(10);

        WCost = new JLabel("enter the Whole Sale cost");
        MPrecentage = new JLabel("Enter the markup precentage");

        button = new JButton("Calculate");
        button.addActionListener(new CalcListerner());

        pannel = new JPanel();
        pannel.add(WholesaleCost);
        pannel.add(markupPresentage);
        pannel.add(WCost);
        pannel.add(MPrecentage);
        pannel.add(button);
    }

    private class CalcListerner implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String WSaleinput;
            String MPres;
            WSaleinput = WholesaleCost.getText();
            MPres = MPrecentage.getText();

            double Value = Double.parseDouble(WSaleinput) * (Double.parseDouble(MPres) / 100);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Retail Price is  " + Value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        mm x = new mm();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error that appears?

Comment: I still don't see it.  Add it directly into your question, as you might not have enough reputation to post links.

Comment: @Vulcan Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Enter the markup precentage"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
 at mm$CalcListerner.actionPerformed(mm.java:58)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
 at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
 ........... many more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to reference the wrong component.

This

```
WSaleinput=WholesaleCost.getText();
MPres =MPrecentage.getText();
```

Should actually be

```
WSaleinput = WholesaleCost.getText();
MPres = markupPresentage.getText();
```

Comment: Basically you said "please java can you convert "Enter the markup precentage" to a double".  Java said, "I can't recognize what you've passed to me as a number or format of a number" - Hence the `NumberFormatException`. It just says, the value is not in recognizable number format that Java can convert.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to parse MPrecentage.getText() to a double, but that's the value of your label, not the value that was input.

You should be setting `MPres` to `markupPercentage.getText();`

The error, NumberFormatException, is one that is thrown if the jvm can't get a number out of the string you give it.  In this case, you are trying to parse a number from the text "Enter the markup precentage"